# How to duplicate list elements according to another counts list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists and I'm trying to create multiple copies of numbers based on how many times they occur.

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2]
amount = [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried:

```
total = []
n = 0
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    product = numbers[n] * amount[n]
    n += 1
    total.extend(product)
```

But I got the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

My expected output is:

```
total = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Change ```total.extend(product)``` to ```total.append(product)``` That will fix your type error, but the code is flawed in the logic, so you won't get the expected result.

Comment: Why are you maintaining `n` when you can just use `i` - the loop's variable?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim your suggested fix will make the code have flawed logic... OP's code simply has two brackets missing to make it work as expected, I wouldn't say his logic is flawed

Answer (score 3):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
result = []
for i, j in zip(numbers, amount):
    result.extend([i] * j)

print(result)
```

---

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is within the line:

```
product = numbers[n] * amount[n]
```

it doesnt result in a list but an integer. Since you're multiplying two numbers.

What you actually want is

```
product = [numbers[n]] * amount[n]
```

---

Try it out here:
https://repl.it/repls/WholeHuskyInterfaces